# Change Context Menu option "Open in Terminal" of Nautilus to launch tilix In Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, context-menu

Trying here without success to change the terminal application to *tilix* when clicking on **Open In Terminal** in context menu of Nautilus; now, it launches *gnome-terminal*.

Already installed and launched *FileManager-Actions Configuration-Tool*, but don't know how to use it.

Comment: Managed to do it as follows, just do as the images shows: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547492/change-ubuntu-18-04-nautilus-context-menu-open-in-terminal-from-gnome-termina

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the terminal to Alacritty in "Open in Terminal" context mneu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245337/how-to-change-the-terminal-to-alacritty-in-open-in-terminal-context-mneu)

Comment: Might do, but did as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547492/change-ubuntu-18-04-nautilus-context-menu-open-in-terminal-from-gnome-termina says.