# How to change the terminal to Alacritty in "Open in Terminal" context mneu?

Tags: command-line, context-menu

I currently using Alacritty terminal. Shortcut works fine. But when I click "Open in Terminal" in context menu, it still pops up the gnome terminal. So is there any way I could change to Alacritty?

Comment: Same question here, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179589/change-context-menu-option-open-in-terminal-of-nautilus-to-launch-tilix-in-ubu?rq=1, but also without valid answer

Comment: That menu entry is specifically added there by *gnome-terminal*'s nautilus plugin, so, by design, it opens gnome-terminal. I don't think there's a ready solution for other terminals.

Answer (score 5):

I installed [manually](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/INSTALL.md) and put the executable in `/usr/local/bin`

I run this command taken from [here](https://frantzroulet.com/blog/other/2018/12/26/how-to-choose-alacritty-as-default-terminal.html) to add an alacritty alternative:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/alacritty 50
```

then I run @walttheboss command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

If you want remove alacritty alternative this is the command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "x-terminal-emulator" "/usr/local/bin/alacritty"
```

Comment: Thank you @israteneda this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you read this [page](https://itsfoss.com/change-default-terminal-ubuntu/).

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

It will show all the terminal emulators present on your system that can be used as default. The current default terminal is marked with the asterisk.

All you have to do is to enter the selection number.

Comment: I did this solution already. As I mentioned above, shortcut works fine but the "Open in Terminal" still opens Gnome terminal.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I thought that changing the default would correct the problem. If you want a particular file type to be opened in terminal then you can associate that with alacrity.  Right click then adjust file type options to your liking.  Then you can "open with" and pick terminal.